# Create FTP account under standard user

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, vps, user-groups

I run multiple client websites on a VPS purchased from Dreamhost.  When I initially set up this VPS, I only required one user.  I created a user called "thoughtspace" with the home directory at /home/thoughtspace.

Recently, a few clients have wanted FTP access to their website for one reason or another.  For example, we host one website called "Footprints on the Moon".  The directory that this website lies in is /home/thoughtspace/rhumbrecht.com.  There are also other websites at /home/thoughtspace/thoughtspacedesigns.com, and other various folders in the same home directory.

How could I go about creating an FTP account that when logged in, would land in /home/thoughtspace/rhumbrecht.com, and wouldn't have access to the parent directory?  Can I add a user with its home directory inside another user home directory?  Will I have to reorganize my entire VPS structure?

Comment: Messed around with Unix groups but couldn't seem to get the desired nested set up that I put above.  Other than that, I've had virtually no dice searching for a way to create a FTP account under a pre-existing user that's only valid for a specific sub folder of the user.

Comment: At this point, I'm almost wondering if the lack of response means I should be putting each site under it's own user account and accessing the server via root for site administration.  Any other ideas that don't involve changing my file structure?